# Putting Powershell variable in double quotes shows Object type instead of value

Tags: powershell

I see this problem in several area, but here is an example

I read an xml document like this and print out a value

```
[xml]$pom = get-content -path pom.xml
PS C:\> $pom.project.artifactId
nexus-peter-test-service
```

However, if I put the value in double quotes, I get this

```
"$pom.project.artifactId"
System.Xml.XmlDocument.project.artifactId
```

I need the value in double quotes because it's part of a long string.  In my case, a url. So I'm using it like this:

```
"/$pom.project.artifactId/"
```

Why does Powershell change the meaning of the variable when in it's double quotes?  And how can I fix this?

Comment: Did you try to use a subexpression?  `"$($pom.project.artifactId)"`

Comment: PowerShell starts to do variable expansion inside strings from left to right. If it expanded successfully `$pom` it will assume the rest of it is a string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the interpolation stops at the period. It interpolates `"$pom"` - which stringifies as the class name - followed by the literal string ".project.artifactId".

To interpolate anything more complex than a simple variable name, you need to wrap `$(...)` around the expression:

```
"$($pom.project.artifactId)"
```